# Confusion about Mono?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, mono

Ok, so I was perusing the mono site and noticed there are Novell tools I can purchase for Visual Studio that will let me choose to compile in Mono?  My confusion is, if I am using a tool set such as MVC 2 and other Frameworks, and I use those tools to compile to mono, how exactly does that play into things?  I mean don't those tool sets need to be recompiled using Mono?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mono can run standard .Net assemblies right out of the box; you don't need to recompile anything for Mono.

Novell's toolset allows Visual Studio to use the Mono runtime when debugging, and includes other features like remote debugging and migration assistance, but it's not required for Mono development.

Comment: So I don't need to recompile the MVC Assemblies to run this say on Linux using Mono as long as I compile my project with Mono?

Comment: You don't need to recompile _anything_ – you don't even need to compile your project with Mono.   However, if the assemblies use APIs that have not been implemented in Mono, it won't work.  (Even if you do recompile)  To check for that, you can run [MoMA](http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA).

Comment: Thank you sir, you are a wealth of knowledge...Very helpful! Wish I could vote you up twice!

Comment: Mono tools for VS allows you to scan using MoMA. Is also support remote debugging in Linux either in local Virtual Machine or in SuseStudio Cloud.